# How to get minutes from DateTimeOffset in C#?

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

Someone gave me an example of this:

LA is behind ‘UTC+0’ by 8hrs, so is in timezone ‘UTC+8’ which is 480mins. The offset value should be the number of minutes to convert the UTCZ datetime back into the local time of the originating system, which in this cast is 480mins behind UTCZ… so the value in utcz_offset_mins should = **-480.  (note the minus sign).**

Im tring with this:

```
DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime.Minute;
```

But it's not accurate, does someone know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for your total offset from UTC in minutes, you need to use following:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.TotalMinutes
```

The code you are trying does not access `Offset` but actually only access `Minute` part of UTC date time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is talking about time zones, but your example code is using the current time. `DateTimeOffset` is an instance of time, similar to `DateTime`, but also incudes the UTC offset. The class you want to use is [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=net-5.0).